# Reset a timer in android

Tags: android

I have a timer running in my android application. I want that after user interaction the timer should reset itself? is there any function like reset() that resets the timer? What is the procedure to reset the timer?

Answer (score 1):

try this I have used this code every where... when I need to restart timer. working fine for me.

```
// FOR CANCELING TIMER AND RESTARTING
my_timer.cancel();
if (my_timer == null) {
    my_timer = new Timer(true);
}
if (my_timer != null) {
    my_timer_task = new TimerTask() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            // CODE YOU WANT TO EXECUTE WHEN TIMER HITS.
        }
    };
}
```

hope it will help you.

Comment: my_timer is an instance of timer() then what is my_timer_task..?

Comment: and once the timer is cancelled i think it cannot schedule again

Comment: I think you need to create your timer object again. Timer task is a block of code which you want to run when timer hits. Timer task is similar to runnable but its executes when timer hits..

Comment: sorry but the question is not relevant but can u tell me a way around how to do unconditional jump in java without break or continue statements?

Comment: I think for your purpose you can use message handler. Just create a message handler and send message to that handler it will execute that code. It works similar to sendMessage in C programming. But in same class.

Comment: i used timer instead of message handler